# Accessing element appended by after()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have appended an textarea to the element using:

```
$('#first').after('<textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea><button></button>');
```

I would like to call a `wysiwyg()` function on that text area:

```
$('#textarea').wysiwyg();
```

This does not work because the element is appended after.

Any advice how to get an element that is appended with the id #textarea in order to call that function on it?

Comment: This *should* work.  Just make sure you are calling `.wysiwyg()` after you have added it to the DOM.

Comment: When would you like to call the wysiwyg?

Comment: what wysiwyg plugin do you use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$(parent_element_of_textarea).on('noevent', '#textarea' ,function(){
     $(this).wysiwyg();
});

$('<textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea><button></button>').insertBefore('#first');
```

Comment: Also a `delegate` method can do the same thing if your jQuery version is too low.

Comment: you should try with ``noevent`` i am not sure if it works, not tested yet ;)

Comment: @doniyor Thank you for the reply!

The containing element of the textarea is also appended, this makes things more complicated i think, but i truly believe your answer is on the right track.